# ReactDOM is not rendering

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx, react-component

```
<div class='row m-b-0'>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">...</div>
 </div>
```

> I am used to using jQuery when I implement like jQuery inside reactjs but in react can not render.

Below is my code.

How can I solve it?

```
render(){

    let tag1 = '';
    let tag2 = '';

    const wrapper = (value,i) => {
        if(i === 1 || i === 4 || i === 7 || i === 10 || i === 13){
            tag1 = "<div class='row m-b-0'>";
        } else {
            tag1 = '';
        }
        if(i === 3 || i === 6 || i === 9 || i === 12 || i === 15){
            tag2 = "</div>";
        } else {
            tag2 = '';
        }
        return (<Content data={i} value={value} tag1={tag1} tag2={tag2} />)
        }

        return(
            <Fragment>
                {
                    this.state.data.map((value,i) =>
                        wrapper(value,i)
                    )
                }
            </Fragment>
        )

    }
}

const Content = (props) => {
    return(
        <Fragment key={props.data}>
        {
            props.tag1
        }
         ...
        {
            props.tag2
        }
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to render 'raw html' in react (f.e. dangerouslySetInnerHTML or fragments) but using react to glue strings/html partials is a bad practice.

React creates (virtual) nodes (fragment) with restrictions - I'm affraid it can't contain tag opening and closing in another node.

You have to structure components closer to required html. In this case (you didn't show data structure) I would divide data in 3-elements sets returning complete ('row') structure/fragment in one step:

```
return (
  <div class='row m-b-0' key={i}>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">{subset[0]}/div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">{subset[1]}/div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">{subset[2]}/div>
  </div>
)
```

Then you can refactor further:

```
return (
  <div class='row m-b-0' key={i}>
    {subset.map((value,i) => (
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" key={i}>{value}</div>
    )}
  </div>
)
```

and later

```
return (
  <div class='row m-b-0' key={i}>
    {subset.map((value,i) => renderCell(value,i) )}
  /div>
)
```

and probably making Cell component

```
return (
  <Row ...props.rowProps key={i}>
    {subset.map((value,i) => <Cell value={value} i={i} ...props.cellProps/> )}
  </Row>
)
```

or if you need simple conditional depth

```
if(!!props.someCond) return (
  <Row ...props.rowProps key={i}>
    {subset.map((value,i) => <Cell value={value} i={i} ...props.cellProps/> )}
  </Row>
}
return (
  <Fragment key={i}>
    {subset.map((value,i) => <Cell value={value} i={i} ...props.cellProps/> )}
  </Fragment>
}
```

or in JSX, sth like:

```
return (
  {!!props.someCond ?
  <Row ...props.rowProps key={i}>
  : <Fragment key={i}>}
  {subset.map((value,i) => <Cell value={value} i={i} ...props.cellProps/> )}
  {!!props.someCond ? </Row> : </Fragment> }
)
```

from some time you can return more than one node and sth like this should work:

```
return (
  {!!props.someCond && <Row ...props.rowProps key={i}>}
  {subset.map((value,i) => <Cell value={value} i={i} ...props.cellProps/> )}
  {!!props.someCond && </Row> }
)
```

There are many possibilities but you have to 'think in react', more structured way ;)

PS. use modulo operator to simplify condition

```
const openingTag = (i>0 && (i % 3 === 1)); // 1,4,7...
const tag1 = openingTag ? `<div class='row m-b-0'>` : null; // null renders nothing in react
```

having prepared boolean value in jsx you can:

```
{openingTag && <div class='row m-b-0'>}
```

but probably it won't work without closing  - use it for entire components or (structured) blocks.